# How do i specify spray Content-Type response header?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I understand that spray does that for me, but I still want to override it with my header, how can I override the header in the response?

My response looks like this:

```
case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/something"), _, _, _) =>
  sender ! HttpResponse(entity = """{ "key": "value" }""" // here i want to specify also response header i would like to explicitly set it and not get it implicitly
```

Comment: Which spray version is that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you still want to use spray can, then you have two options, based on that HttpResponse is a case class. The first is to pass a List with an explicit content type:

```
import spray.http.HttpHeaders._
import spray.http.ContentTypes._

def receive = {
    case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/something"), _, _, _) =>
      sender ! HttpResponse(entity = """{ "key": "value" }""", headers = List(`Content-Type`(`application/json`)))
  }
```

Or, the second way, is to use a method `withHeaders` method:

```
def receive = {
    case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/something"), _, _, _) =>
      val response: HttpResponse = HttpResponse(entity = """{ "key": "value" }""")
      sender ! response.withHeaders(List(`Content-Type`(`application/json`)))
  }
```

But still, like [jrudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7647/jrudolph) said, it's much better to use spray routing, in this case it would look better:

```
def receive = runRoute {
    path("/something") {
      get {
        respondWithHeader(`Content-Type`(`application/json`)) {
          complete("""{ "key": "value" }""")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But spray makes it even easier and handles all (un)marshalling for you:

```
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

def receive = runRoute {
  (path("/something") & get) {
    complete(Map("key" -> "value"))
  }
}
```

In this case reponse type will be set to `application/json` by the spray itself.

Complete example for my comment:

```
class FullProfileServiceStack
  extends HttpServiceActor
     with ProfileServiceStack
     with ... {
  def actorRefFactory = context
  def receive = runRoute(serviceRoutes)
}

object Launcher extends App {
  import Settings.service._
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Profile-Service")
  import system.log

  log.info("Starting service actor")
  val handler = system.actorOf(Props[FullProfileServiceStack], "ProfileActor")

  log.info("Starting Http connection")
  IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(handler, interface = host, port = port)
}
```

Comment: I added the imports but i get `not found: value runRoute
  def receive = runRoute {
                ^`

Comment: @Tomer to have it you need to `extend Actor with HttpService` or just `extends HttpServiceActor` from spray routing package

Comment: in the last example is it supposed also to work on a servlet container?

Comment: @Tomer You can, as i know, but i've never tried with servlets, i'm using spray-can and akka.

Comment: @Tomer i've added a little example of one project which is running on top of akka + spray-can

Answer (score 3):

The `entity` parameter of `HttpResponse` is actually of type `HttpEntity` and your string is only implicitly converted into an instance of `HttpEntity`. You can use one of the other constructors to specify a content-type. See [the source](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/HttpEntity.scala#L41) for the possible constructors in the nightly version of spray.

Also if you use spray-routing, you can leave marshalling/unmarshalling to the infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

In recent version of Spray (1.2.4 / 1.3.4), you may want to use `respondWithMediaType`. Here is [the sample from the documentation](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/respond-with-directives/respondWithMediaType/#respondwithmediatype) :

```
val route =
  path("foo") {
    respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
      complete("[]") // marshalled to `text/plain` here
    }
  }
```

Note that while this overrides the HTTP header value, it will not override the marshaller used for serializing your content to the wire.

Therefore using a recent spray with spray routing, the original code would look like :

```
def receive = runRoute {
  path("/something") {
    get {
      respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
        complete("""{ "key": "value" }""")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to 4lex1v's answer, there is a very nice, short, simple, working (as of 4/15, scala 2.11.5) tutorial on the GeoTrellis site, including a `build.sbt`. The GeoTrellis pieces are also straightforward to eliminate for the purposes of this stack overflow question.

http://geotrellis.io/tutorials/webservice/spray/