# Spray 1.2 ignores content-type header in response

Tags: spray, spray-dsl

I am trying to set application/json as content-Type in a spray-routing actor. But the content-type i see in my response always is text/plain. I tried using the spray-routing approach ("something") and the spray-can approacch ("something2") but the two routes don't send the response-type properly. Did I miss something?

```
def receive = runRoute {        
    path("something") {
      get {
        respondWithHeader(`Content-Type`(`application/json`)) {
          complete("""{ "key": "value" }""")
        }
      }
    } ~
    path("something2") {
      get {
        complete(HttpResponse(entity = """{ "key": "value" }""").withHeaders((List(`Content-Type`(`application/json`)))))
      }
    }
  }`enter code here`
```

Comment: I tried to use the code examples from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396187/how-do-i-specify-spray-content-type-response-header but they do not work for me

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the responseheader is overwritten by the marshaller for string.

Like this it works like a charm:

```
path("something") {
  get {
    respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
      complete("""{ "key": "value" }""")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a much better approach to return a `json` with a `application/json` content type with  `spray.json` module. If you have just `key:value` pairs it would be much cleaner to use SprayJsonMarshaller, which would authomatically set appropriate header. Consider the following example:

```
(get & path("somePath")) { complete(Map("key" -> "value")) }
```

To make a json response you just need to import two things:

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._ // contains default marshallers
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._   // will do all the headers work
```

If you have your own case class which you would like to send over the wire, then provide a converter into json format:

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class SomeClass(name: String)
object SomeClass {
  implicit val someClassJson = jsonFormat1(SomeClass.apply)
}
```

It's a much better approach cause if you later would like to change the format in you response, all you need to do is to change a marshaller, the rewrite your code.

number in the end of jsonFormat method equals to the number of case class arguments.